# Pushing data in keys into a single array only values

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Such data is coming from Laravel to Ajax. How do I push the values ​​inside the keys into a single array without the keys.

```
$get_session = session()->get('cart.products');
return response($get_session);
```

Data returned to Ajax.

```
data1: {
1234543: {id: 1, title: 'Product Title1', description: 'Product Descrition1'}
3453234: {id: 2, title: 'Product Title2', description: 'Product Descrition2'}
4564234: {id: 3, title: 'Product Title3', description: 'Product Descrition3'} 
}

data2: {
4643345: {id: 4, title: 'Product Title4', description: 'Product Descrition4'}
8679673: {id: 5, title: 'Product Title5', description: 'Product Descrition5'}
2344565: {id: 6, title: 'Product Title6', description: 'Product Descrition6'}
}
```

this is what i want to do

```
[
1234543: {id: 1, title: 'Product Title1', description: 'Product Descrition1'}
3453234: {id: 2, title: 'Product Title2', description: 'Product Descrition2'}
4564234: {id: 3, title: 'Product Title3', description: 'Product Descrition3'} 
4643345: {id: 4, title: 'Product Title4', description: 'Product Descrition4'}
8679673: {id: 5, title: 'Product Title5', description: 'Product Descrition5'}
2344565: {id: 6, title: 'Product Title6', description: 'Product Descrition6'}
]
```

How can I do it with Laravel or jquery? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you want to get only the keys in an array or you want to get both the keys and its values?

Comment: I want to push the values ​​in data1 and data2 into a single array. @ruleboy21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you get the ajax response as `response`, you can convert it to the expected object like so

```
var data = Object.assign(...Object.values(response));
```

Example

```js
var response = {
    data1: {
        1234543: {id: 1, title: 'Product Title1', description: 'Product Descrition1'},
        3453234: {id: 2, title: 'Product Title2', description: 'Product Descrition2'},
        4564234: {id: 3, title: 'Product Title3', description: 'Product Descrition3'}
    },
    data2: {
        4643345: {id: 4, title: 'Product Title4', description: 'Product Descrition4'},
        8679673: {id: 5, title: 'Product Title5', description: 'Product Descrition5'},
        2344565: {id: 6, title: 'Product Title6', description: 'Product Descrition6'}
    }
};
var data = Object.assign(...Object.values(response));
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return response()->json([$get_session['data1']]);
```

Comment: "[$get_session['data1']+$get_session['data2']]"  that's how it works. But it will get longer when there are more keys

Comment: Array structure in php does not need a plus sign @B.Grgr

Comment: I don't know, it worked with plus sign but I used it in laravel. @shahriyar3